# Flutter: Passing AppLocalizations.of(context)!.actionaid into initalUrl of a webview

Tags: flutter, webview, localization

I am currently localizing my app, I have translates all the webpages to be opened and added the url to my arb files.

But when i call the `AppLocalizations.of(context)!.actionaid` on `initialUrl` i get a red underline saying `Invalid constant value`

Is there any way I could make this work?

Thanks guys

I have something like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

class actionAid extends StatelessWidget {
 const actionAid({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return const CupertinoPageScaffold(
  navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(middle: Text("Action Aid")),
  child: SafeArea(
    child: WebView(
      initialUrl:  AppLocalizations.of(context)!.actionaid,
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
    ),
    //bottomNavigationBar: CustomBottomNavBar(selectedMenu: MenuState.give),
  ),
);
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are defining your Widget tree to only contain constant values by writing `const CupertinoPageScaffold`.

Since `AppLocalization.of(context).actionaid` is not providing a constant value this "rule" gets violated and triggers the error.

Changing `const CupertinoPageScaffold` to just `CupertinoPageScaffold` or extracting the `WebView` widget into a separate widget with a const constructor should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, @daniellampl I didn't even notice that. It happens